# Generating a random complex vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, vector, complex-numbers

I am trying to generate a set of k, random, unit, complex vectors with n components in matlab.

I understand that there can be some issues with making sure the resulting vectors are isotropic. Would something like the following work?

```
vectors=exp(2i*pi*rand(k,n)).*randn(k,n);
for i=1:k
    vectors(i,:)=vectors(i,:)/norm(vectors(i,:);
end
```

Thanks for your help,

Stan

Comment: see this answer on how "A random normal distribution of coordinates gives you a uniform distribution of directions." - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750908/how-to-generate-a-unit-vector-pointing-in-a-random-direction-with-isotropic-dist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be fine.  The key is that multidimensional normal random variables are already spherically symmetric (isotropic).  The random angle, though, seems a little clunky.  I would just use more `randn`:

```
vectors = complex(randn(k,n), randn(k,n));
```

Then continue with the normalization step.  Here's a vectorized version of the normalization:

```
vectors = bsxfun(@rdivide, vectors, sqrt(sum(vectors.*conj(vectors), 2)));
```

Comment: but this would not give a uniform distribution in the angle whereas the OPs would?

Comment: Yes, it would.  Multidimensional gaussian is isotropic.  Try it: `hist(angle(complex(randn(1000000,1), randn(1000000,1))));`  If you use rand instead of randn, you're exactly right.

Comment: Dear Peter, the sum is in the wrong direction: 
    X = complex(randn(D, N), randn(D, N));
    X = bsxfun(@rdivide, X, sqrt(sum(X .* conj(X), 1)));

Comment: The sum can be in whatever direction you want it.  I wrote `sum(..., 2)` to match the conventions preferred by the OP.  If you want column vectors instead of row vectors, then by all means normalize over the columns instead by summing along the first dimension.