# Iterate over all vectors of length `L`

Tags: c++, combinatorics

How can I iterate over all possible vectors of `d` dimensions with specified length (e.g. unit length), where `delta` is the step-size.

---

Note that `delta` can by quite small, such as `1e-3` for a unit vector. `d` is commonly in the range of `[0,5]` but this is not a hard restriction!.

---

The dumb approach would be to use a list of `delta*i` for `i in [0,N)` and generate all possible combos like in n choose n and select those which sum up to `1`. But this seems to be quite inefficient and I am sure there are better approaches which I am not aware of.

---

The picks should be at least close to uniformly distributed over the surface.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates

Comment: As I said, `delta` is the smallest change of one dimension that is allowed. That rasterizes the problem and goes from uncountable many to a restricted range.

Comment: In 2D, you can just generate a set of angles, from which you can calculate the vector components. In 3D (spherical coordinates), you need 2 angles. I'm sure this generalizes to the D-dimensional case. Edit: see @sbabbi above

Comment: why don't you just use a N-dimensional spherical coordinates parametrization, then discretize each independent coordinate? The number of possible solutions scales as K^N, where K is the number of steps in a 1-D discretization, and N is the number of dimensions. That is, there are quite a lot of such vectors :)

Comment: If `delta` is the smallest allowable change along **one dimension**, then you will get unusual concentrations of samples.  It will not be close to an even distribution.  Is that what you want?  *(Put another way, Cartesian coordinates do not map smoothly to a spheroid surface)*

Comment: @DrewDormann Having a uniform distribution is a different ball game, a bit more complicated, but see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html for some hints. And I guess the whole business depends on how you parametrize the manifold. If you use cartesian coordinates, then of course you get far from uniform distributions.

Comment: Uniform distribution over the surface would be preferable. The difficulty is not to implement it for 1,2,3 or 4 dimensions but to make it generic for `d`-dimensions.

Comment: @drahnr then generate each component of the vector using a random normal distribution, then normalize it. In MATLAB code (just to illustrate the point): `v = randn(1,3); v = v/norm(v)` assures you that `v` is distributed uniformly on the surface of a unit  3-D ball. So the cartesian coordinates have to be normally distributed. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9751925/3093378 Now I am not sure what exactly `delta` is? Is it the difference between 2 such vectors?

Comment: @drahnr I have to say that the problem doesn't seem so trivial, and I guess it is not at all related to C++, but to math and combinatorics. You should try posting it on mathoverflow also. One thing you may want to check: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24688/efficiently-sampling-points-uniformly-from-the-surface-of-an-n-sphere

Comment: You should start out by defining "length".  1-norm and infinity-norm have simple solutions, 2-norm is likely very interesting.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about geometry and combinatorics in general and not a specific programming language or a specific programming question.

Comment: Eh no, it is perfectly on topic. All I need is homegenous spacing of smaple points (like equal distance, not statistically evenly distributed points) on an _n-dimensional_ sphere. My issue here is implementing it for n dimensions. Sure the transformation into r space does work but is not easy for `n>4` and the general case

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured out what you need. Basically, if you choose

```
X=(X1, X2, ..., Xn)/norm(X)
```

where `X1, X2,..., Xn` are normally distributed `N(0,1)` (mean 0 and standard deviation 1) and `norm(X)` is the L2 (Euclidian) norm of `X`, then it is guaranteed that the vector `X` is uniformly distributed across the surface of the `n`-dimensional unit sphere.

Now, since you want to discretize, just draw each `Xi` from a binomial distribution (which at the limit we know it becomes a Poisson distribution, which, via the Central Limit theorem, converges to a Gaussian distribution, see http://www.roe.ac.uk/japwww/teaching/astrostats/astrostats2012_part2.pdf ), and you're done. Of course, you'll get an exponential scaling in the dimension `n`, but I don't think there is any other way, as the number of such vectors scale exponentially with the dimension.

Comment: That is a clever use of the gaussian distribution.

Comment: @sbabbi, I wish the first part was my original idea :)

Comment: discrete Xi aren't helpful, since you need Xi/norm(X) to lie on the lattice

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, that's true... seems a bit more complicated than I though, at least more complicated than a Sunday night problem :) One idea is to pick components from `N(0,1)` subjected to a restriction that their norm lies within `epsilon` from the surface (if you want strict equality you get into diophantine equations which are a pain in the neck). But again, I'd love to see a proper rigorous answer to the question, I just gave the physicist's proof :)) And I hope OP posts it on mathoverflow, since that is the site it belongs to, as it has not too much to do with C++

Comment: But that does not guarantee a spacing of delta, so I not only need homegenous distribution, but also equal distances between the sample vectors. Sorry if misguided you here.